# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException binding java library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, computer-vision, android-camera2, uvc

I'm trying to bind the libuvccamera java library to access UVC camera in Android device developing in Xamarin.Android, and during the binding of the [libuvccamera.aar and the usbCameraCommon.aar](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) file I've a lot of trouble. Once of this is the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException that was called when a called the USBMonitor costructor of the java class:

```
    USBMonitor usb_monitor; 

    try
    {
        usb_monitor = new USBMonitor(this, this);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

I've imported the .arr libraries as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar)
[image]

but when I create the distribution and run the application to my Android device I get the exception call as below:

```
Failed resolution of: Lcom/serenegiant/utils/HandlerThreadHandler;
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <94b04e1756104d1fa1d144932ae2720c>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:444 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (System.IntPtr instance, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr constructorId, Android.Runtime.JValue* constructorParameters) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:362 
  at Com.Serenegiant.Usb.USBMonitor..ctor (Android.Content.Context context, Com.Serenegiant.Usb.USBMonitor+IOnDeviceConnectListener listener) [0x000df] in C:\dev\code\curr\LETTURA_DATA_MATRIX_LUXOTTICA\DEMO\TEST_UVC_CAMERA_LIB\TEST_3\LIBUVC\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Serenegiant.Usb.USBMonitor.cs:1076 
  at TEST_3.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0001e] in C:\dev\code\curr\LETTURA_DATA_MATRIX_LUXOTTICA\DEMO\TEST_UVC_CAMERA_LIB\TEST_3\TEST_3\MainActivity.cs:28 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError stack trace ---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/serenegiant/utils/HandlerThreadHandler;
    at com.serenegiant.usb.USBMonitor.<init>(USBMonitor.java:122)
    at crc645ed0f3853a61fd03.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc645ed0f3853a61fd03.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.serenegiant.utils.HandlerThreadHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.test_3-RASdU4LTR0mcU0jXj9KO8Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.test_3-RASdU4LTR0mcU0jXj9KO8Q==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.companyname.test_3-RASdU4LTR0mcU0jXj9KO8Q==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 18 more
```

Some suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I've to implement in the .arr library the HandlerThreadHandler class, so the costructor of the USBMonitor class can found it.